# Optimized multi-data curve fitting

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a force vs displacement multi-data set with each curve obtained at constant current value. I want to curve fit the data using electromagnetic force equation. F (x,i )=(β(i)^2)/((κ-x)^2). What value of current 'i' should be selected to obtain an single optimized fit of multi-data set?

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/interactive-fit-comparison.html)?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data? You should be able to fit a 3D surface, I will try.

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1406108/. My experimental data is similar to force vs air gap graph in this article.  Each curve gives a value of parameters β and κ. I want to find optimized parameter values that will represent all the curves. What current value must be used in the equation used for fitting? Hope you understand my question.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it says I can purchase the article. While I would like to help you, my request was for data. F(x,i) seems like a surface fit which I can do using the equation you provided, but I cannot fit data that I do not have.